# What's the difference between "$A$ has a unique right inverse" and "$A$ has a right inverse", where $A$ is a non-square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I'm studying Linear Algebra, and I worked through some past tests. What I realized is that two statements, of almost the same "nature", had two different outcomes. The first one was:

> "$A$ has a unique right inverse" and "$A$ has a right inverse", where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, such that it's not square.

Now, I know I haven't given out any information about the matrix $A$. But let's suppose that $A$ is the same for both statements. Is there any difference in asking whether it has a unique right inverse, or whether it has a right inverse? I'm assuming that asking whether $A$ has a unique right inverse, is the same as asking if $A$ has an inverse, since the inverse is always unique. However, since $A$ isn't square, a unique inverse can't exist.

Thanks.

Comment: "*Since the (right) inverse is always unique*"  Citation needed.  Do not confuse statements made about *right inverses* and statements made about *(double-sided) inverses*.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}=[1]=I_{1\times 1}$.  What is "the" right inverse of $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JMoravitz.

Comment: Only invertible square matrices and empty matrices with zero rows have unique right inverses.